# How can I present a ViewController using applicationdidBecomeActive func with some exceptions?

Tags: swift, background, uiimagepickercontroller, appdelegate

Using applicationDidBecomeActive in AppDelegate is a good way of presenting a specific ViewController each time an ios app becomes active. But how can I override This function and make a few exceptions of when to show the view controller or not after the app becomes active again. When I pick an image from UIImgaePickerController, the view controller shows up again. how can I make my app active even if it’s not to avoid the rootcontroller assigned in applicationDidBecomeActive() to popup again.

Comment: use UserDefaults and store a value on first time. then check every time it has value or not.

Comment: I have so many UserDefaults already, it’s confusing I want something else. Btw this won’t work at all. I have three root ViewControllers and i want to change them inside some functions

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly you want to change the root view controller when something happens while using your app, so you can put this piece of code in your `AppDelegate`: this just catches the current `rootViewController`, set the new one and dismisses and remove the old one inside a transition

```
func changeRootViewController(with viewController: UIViewController) {
guard let oldViewController = self.window?.rootViewController else { return }
UIView.transition(from: oldViewController.view, to: viewController.view, duration: 0.3, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve, .allowAnimatedContent]) { _ in
    self.window!.rootViewController = viewController
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    oldViewController.dismiss(animated: false) {
        oldViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
}
```

then, when you need to change the `rootViewController` you can just:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
appDelegate?.changeRootViewController(with: MyNewViewController())
```